# lstlisting - giving source - smaller font, alongside caption, preferably above caption

Tags: listings, footnotes, sourcecode, source

I would like to separate description of listing (`\caption{}`) from source of listing. What I search for is like `\footnotesize` in presenting pictures (`\begin{figure}`). I was searching for this at [latex lstlisting wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) but I didn't find any fitting option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}   
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.64]{example-image-a}
        \textsuperscript{Source and some text to reproduce the problem of non-hyphenation: \url{http://google.com/}}
        \caption{Schema}
        \label{abc}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=incode, caption={Verification}, label={lst:verification}]
    let signature = try Signature(base64Encoded: "AAA===")
    let isSuccessful = try clear.verify(with: publicKey, signature: signature, digestType: .sha1)
\end{lstlisting}

\FloatBarrier   


\end{document}
```

@edit
I added some minimal working example as Andrew suggested.

Comment: you can add anything before the listing environment and finish it with `\vspace*{-25pt}`  for example to come close to the listing caption. But your question is not clear enough. (Also you had an answer in previous question that did not accepted yet. If the answer is good for you... just accept it by clicking on the "tick" sign next to it.)

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you wanted if you added [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you are doing: without code that exhibits your problem we have to guess what you are doing, which makes it almost impossible to help you.

Comment: If `listings` can float, you can use a `figure` environment with a `listing` inside and a regular `caption` command. if you don't want floating listings, load `capt-of`package to use `\captionof` command for nonfloating captions.

Comment: @Ignasi The problem with figure is that I need that smaller font caption (`\textsuperscript` or `\footnotesize`) between the code and the normal caption. On the other hand I couldn't manage to add `captionof` in my type of listing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it you are asking to insert extra material between the end of the code listing and before the caption.  Here is one suggestion for this, providing the new material via an `extradescription` key to the `lstlisting`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\makeatletter
\def\lst@extradescription{\@empty}
\lst@Key{extradescription}{\@empty}{\def\lst@extradescription{#1}%
  \def\lst@captionpos{b}}
\def\lst@makecaption{\ifx\lst@extradescription\@empty\else
  \begin{center}\tiny\lst@extradescription\end{center}\par\fi\@makecaption}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Verification}, label={lst:verification},
  extradescription={\includegraphics[scale=0.64]{example-image-a}\\[1ex]Source
  and text description.\\More of the extra description.}]
    let signature = try Signature(base64Encoded: "AAA===")
    let isSuccessful = try clear.verify(with: publicKey)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The primitive to define additional keys to `lstlisting` is the internal command `\lst@Key` which takes as arguments the key name, the default value of the key and the associated code.  In this case I have provided

```
\lst@Key{extradescription}{\@empty}{\def\lst@extradescription{#1}%
  \def\lst@captionpos{b}}
```

which creates a key `extradescription` and stores its argument in `\lst@extradescription`.  It also forces the caption placement argument `captionpos` to be `b` so the caption appears at the bottom of the listing.  The code

```
\def\lst@makecaption{\ifx\lst@extradescription\@empty\else
  \begin{center}\tiny\lst@extradescription\end{center}\par\fi\@makecaption}
```

replaces the standard caption making code of `listings` by code that first prints the extra description (if non-empty) in a `center` environment with `\tiny` font, and then proceeds with the usual caption building material.

As the above involves internal macros with `@` in their name it is necessary to include the coding in `\makeatletter...\makeatother`.

Answer (score 2):

Just assuming you want to distinguish different subfigures with each its own caption, I would suggest looking at the [subfloat](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats) package. Being both highly flexible and adding a smaller caption below each figure. As a bonus you can reference each subfig.

```
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{gull}
            \caption{A gull}
            \label{fig:gull}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
          %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{tiger}
            \caption{A tiger}
            \label{fig:tiger}
        \end{subfigure}
        ~ %add desired spacing between images, e. g. ~, \quad, \qquad, \hfill etc. 
        %(or a blank line to force the subfigure onto a new line)
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{mouse}
            \caption{A mouse}
            \label{fig:mouse}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Pictures of animals}\label{fig:animals}
    \end{figure}
```

[image: result]